# How to trigger form_Load event with button click

Tags: c#

I've done all the things in the form load event but because of the fact that it isn't triggering more than once in my code I can't reach the rest of the code , it just handles the first part .

This is the code that works with form.Load but there are many of this one because I'm designing an two elimination bracket and what I want is at the beginning all buttons are enabled = False  except the first 16 player then when 8 buttons are clicked the next 8 winner button is going to be enable=true and I should be able to click these 8 buttons .  But in this code I can do the first 16 but when they are enabled=false and the next 8 buttons come as enabled=true ,  I cannot change their colors to green because form.Load just enter these codes at the beginning.

```
  private void _4teamDoubleElimination_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)                           // LOAD LOAD LOAD LOAD LOAD LOAD LOAD LOAD LOAD 
        {
            static void deneme()
            {

            }


            int roundCount = 0;
            int i = 0;
            Shuffle(form2ye_Gidecek_Veri);
            foreach (Button button in new Button[] { buttonR1_1, buttonR1_2, buttonR1_3, buttonR1_4 })          // VERİLERİN ILK KEZ ALINMASI       ama tekli sayılarda sorun cıkartır
            {
                button.Text = form2ye_Gidecek_Veri[i];
                i++;
            }



            // 1.TUR
            var Round1All = new[] { buttonR1_1, buttonR1_2, buttonR1_3, buttonR1_4 };
            var Round2Winner = new[] { buttonR2_1, buttonR2_2 };
            var Round2Loser = new[] { buttonLoseR1_1, buttonLoseR1_2 };
            var Round3Winner = new[] { buttonR3_1 };                                     // BUTONLARIN ARRAY'E ALINMASI  VE RENKLENDİRME
            var Round3Loser = new[] { buttonLoseR1_1, buttonLoseR1_2 };





            colorGreen(Round1All);
            colorGreen(Round2Loser);
            colorGreen(Round2Winner);
            colorGreen(Round3Loser);
            colorGreen(Round3Winner);

            enabledFalse(Round2Loser);
            enabledFalse(Round2Winner);
            enabledFalse(Round3Loser);
            enabledFalse(Round3Winner);




            foreach (var button in Round1All)
                { 
                            button.Click += (sender, e) =>
                            {
                            if (checkNextRoundAvaliability(Round1All).Equals(true))
                            {
                                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(" Sonraki tura geçeceksiniz ", " Onaylıyor musunuz ? ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                                {
                                    enabledTrue(Round2Loser);

                                    roundCount += 1;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    int j = 0;
                                    getNextRoundWinnerData(Round1All);
                                    getNextRoundLoserData(Round1All);
                                    foreach (var button in Round2Winner)                               // 2. RAUND UN VERİLERİ
                                    {
                                        button.Text = listBoxForWinner.Items[i].ToString();
                                        i++;

                                    }

                                    foreach (var button in Round2Loser)
                                    {
                                        button.Text = listBoxForLoser.Items[j].ToString();
                                        j++;
                                  
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                            }
                            };
                
                 }




                         // LOSER ROUND 1              
                foreach (var button in Round2Loser)
                {
                    button.Click += (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            if (checkNextRoundAvaliability(Round2Loser).Equals(true))
                            {
                                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sonraki tura geçeceksiniz ", "Onaylıyor musunuz ? ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                                {
                                    roundCount += 1;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    int j = 0;
                                    getNextRoundWinnerData(Round2Loser);
                                    getNextRoundLoserData(Round2Loser);
                                    foreach (var button in Round2Loser)                               // 2. RAUND UN VERİLERİ
                                    {
                                        button.Text = listBoxForWinner.Items[i].ToString();
                                        i++;
                                    }

                                    foreach (var button in Round2Loser)
                                    {
                                        button.Text = listBoxForLoser.Items[j].ToString();
                                        j++;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        };

                }
           







                      // WINNER ROUND 2          
                foreach (var button in Round2Winner)
                {
                    button.Click += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (checkNextRoundAvaliability(Round2Winner).Equals(true))
                        {
                            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sonraki tura geçeceksiniz ", "Onaylıyor musunuz ? ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                getNextRoundWinnerData(Round2Winner);
                                getNextRoundLoserData(Round2Winner);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    };

                }
            
        }
```

Comment: More the stuff in an own method and call it from both Form_Load and any other place you need it.

Comment: @KlausGütter I made a method but I can't reach the variables that I defined in form.Load

Comment: @Dai at first there are 16 buttons then 8 then 4 then 2 . These loops are for click event , when clicked their color goes green and when the last button comes they are becomes enabled=false and the next round comes and I take the green ones as the next round's items

Comment: "the variables that I defined in form.Load" - you did not show us your complete Form_Load code so I have no idea what these variables are.

Comment: @KlausGütter I edited the question and here is my all form.Load

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Form_Load event from your Button_CLick event.

```
public void Form_Load(object? sender, EventArgs? e) // added '?' to avoid null warning
{
  // code
}

public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  From_Load(null, null)
}
```

**However** it is not recommended as evets should only be triggered when the event actually happens.

Instead create a new Method and call it by both events.

EDIT for the comment:

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  NewMethod();
}

public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  NewMethod();
}

public void NewMethod()
{
  //Your code
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to call it by both events . Can you instruct me more detailed please  ? I tried creating a method outside the form.Load but this time method cannot reach form.Load 's variables

Comment: You cam just move your code from the Form_Load method to a new Method.
Edited my awnser for you :)

Comment: the problem is not reaching variables in form.Load within the method . I can call method in button_click but I can't refer to the variables in form.Load in button_click . For example , I want to give a variable in form.Load as a parameter to method.